# Evaluate : $\displaystyle\int\limits_{\gamma }\frac{\log (1+z)}{1+z}dz$

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Computer
$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{\gamma }\frac{\log (1+z)}{1+z}dz$$
Where :

$$\gamma =\{ |z|=1~ ; ~\Re z≥0,\Im z≥0 \}$$

I try :

$z=e^{it}$ then $dz=ie^{it}dt$
And $t\in [0,\frac{π}{2}$ then integration become :

$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}\frac{\log (1+e^{it})}{1+e^{it}}dz$$
Using :

$$\log (1+e^{it})=\ln |1+e^{it}|+i \arg (1+e^{it})$$

but I don't know how I complete ?
Can you assist ?

---

Thanks!

Comment: Would you accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

The intgrand has "problems" at $x=-1$ but the curve $\gamma$ is far from it
$$
\int \frac{\ln(1+z)}{1+z}dz 
=\int \frac{\ln(u)}{u}du 
=\int \ln(u)d(\ln(u)) 
=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(u) +c 
=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1+z) +c
$$
The limits of the integral are $z_1 = e^{i0} = 1$ and $z_2 = e^{i\pi/2} = i$
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{\ln(1+z)}{1+z}dz = \frac{1}{2}(\ln^2(1+e^{i\pi/2}) - \ln^2(1+1)) 
= \frac{1}{2}(\ln^2(1+i) - \ln^2(2))\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln^2(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/2}) - \ln^2(2)\right)
= -\frac{3\ln^2(2)+\pi^2}{8} + i\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you  much sir

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: @physor how you get the limits of integral? I use $z=e^{it}$ also but I think limits $0\to \frac{π}{2}$